# Django "if request.method == 'POST':" fails

Tags: html, django, post

Hi have a strange problem in my new Django project.

I'm testing basically the *NameForm* example from the [Django Documentation Working with Froms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/). It seems to be an easy one but somehow when I try to submit some name nothing happens even not a page reload.

**form.py**

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
     your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from groupbuilder import forms

def GroupBuilder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = forms.NameForm()


    return render(request, 'groupbuilder.html', {'form': form})
```

**the template:**

```
    <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          { form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

**setting.py**

```
"""
Django settings for crossLFG project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.tz",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
    #"frontpage.context_processors.contactform",
)


DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_PATH = '/home/KBrothers/crossLFG/'
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'users.db')
#LOCALE_PATHS = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'locale',)
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/home/KBrothers/crossLFG/locale',)



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ****

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'main_app',
    'groupbuilder',

    'crispy_forms',

)



TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'main_app/templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'accounts/templates'),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'groupbuilder/templates'),

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crossLFG.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crossLFG.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

MAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = '****'
EMAIL_PORT = ****
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '********'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'

#CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': DATABASE_PATH,                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
#LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'wm_lang'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

LANGUAGES = (

    ('en', _('English')),
    #('de', _('German')),
    #('fr', _('French')),
)







USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/
```

The strange thing is if I put

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

right after the "else" in the

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

statement, I can't even fill out the form when I try to visit the form URL. It takes my directly to /thanks/. So the request.method check always fails.

What do I miss??

Comment: Is there any error on the console? What happens, when your request is a `POST` request, but the form is not valid? Are you sure, you pass valid data to your form? Try to debug into the code: paste `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` before the `if` statement. When the interpreter 'hits' this line, you'll get a 'stupid' Python shell in the console. What does the request.method says in that case?

Comment: The behaviour you describe if you put the redirect after else is exactly what you should expect: when you load the page initially, method is GET.

Comment: The `pdb.set_trace()`fails with `No exception message supplied`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/plugins/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
```

from [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) caused the problem. I'm not very sure why but there must have been some interference with some form functionalities.

Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your template code: `{ form.as_p }}`  add '{'

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

If the form field is

```
your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=5, required = True)
```

and I just hit the Submit button without filling in a name, nothing happens. No reload page, no error messages (as the field is set to "required").

If instead I define the field as

```
your_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)), label=("our name"))
```

and I hit Submit without name I do get an Django form field error

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).